# How can an InfoPath form get the Claims of the user who is logged in to SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, claims-based-identity, infopath2010, claims

We have a document library that contains a list of proposals (InfoPath Forms). Users log in through SharePoint using Claims (Forms Auth, via an Extranet) who are from various organizations. The forms open in InfoPath on the client. The InfoPath form contains a field for what organization the proposal belongs to (a select list) that the user then selects when filling the form.

We have written a custom claims provider that augments each user's login with an organization claim.

When the user opens a proposal from SharePoint in the InfoPath form filler, we'd like to:

- Pre-populate the organization select list with the organization
  matching the user's claim
- Restrict the saving of the form (inserting and updating) if the
  user's claim value for organization does not match the selected
  organization on the form

I'm wondering how to get the claims information in InfoPath. Or, for ideas on how to do this server-side using a custom workflow/event receiver/web service (or something else).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic tutorial for getting claims from SharePoint 2010. Place this in the code behind of your InfoPath form. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535731.aspx

Ideally you want to call the code from the FormEvents_Loading method of your InfoPath form and if the user's organization is invalid, create a bool, that if false, will prevent the form from submitting. This would be done in the FormEvents_Submit method.

Comment: I have already created the custom claims provider as per the Microsoft link. The tricky part is with reading the claim in the InfoPath form, can you elaborate on those details?

Comment: I've actually never done this specifically but there is some good sample code in the pdf located http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27569 Good luck!

Comment: The sample code is implementing a custom claims provider (again, I already have a working implementation of a claims provider). I don't see anything that is able to get the user's Claims from within InfoPath.

Comment: Sorry I might have misread your question. Can you not get a users Claims from the code behind of an InfoPath form?

Comment: I think that's the same question that I'm asking. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works for your specific implementation however, you can set the data source for input controls (drop down lists, list boxes, etc) to be retreived from a web service.

You can then use hidden fields on the eForm which are populated with the metadata you need such as the user Id. These values are subsequently passed to the webservice and the return (List or whatever) are bound to the desired controls within the eForm.

Comment: Hmm, so on the server-side, how would you look up claims for an arbitrary user id? (Given that my custom claim is only assigned to the user when the user themselves logs in)